# ¿Como eliminar un documento pdf en laravel?

Tags: laravel, pdf

Tengo un programa que sube un archivo a partir de un formulario y en el caso de que ya exista lo borra para subir el nuevo(lo actualiza) a partir del mismo formulario y también tengo una interface donde te muestra el pdf subido... Si no existe o es la primera vez que se sube, sin problema guarda el pdf y los muestra en la interface... El problema es cuando ya existe el pdf, digamos que si guarda el nuevo documento pero en la interface muestra el anterior, tiene que pasar mucho tiempo para que muestre el actualizado lo cual se me hace muy raro. ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

```
public function uploadpolitics(Request $request){

    $message = request()->validate([
        'pdf' => 'required',            //Hacemos que valide el nombre, en caso de no ser valido regresa al formulario.
        'id_corp' => 'required',
        'type_pdf' => 'required',   
      ]); 

    $file = $request->file("pdf");

    if($file->guessExtension()=="pdf"){

      $name = $request->id_corp.".".$file->guessExtension();

      if ($request->type_pdf == "contrato") {
        $ruta = public_path("politics/contract/".$name);
        $insertPath = DB::table('empresas')->where('empresa_id',$request->id_corp)->update(['path_contrato' => 'politics/contract/'.$name]);

      }elseif ($request->type_pdf == "politicas") {

        $ruta = public_path("politics/politics/".$name);
        $insertPath = DB::table('empresas')->where('empresa_id',$request->id_corp)->update(['path_politicas' => 'politics/politics/'.$name]);
      }
    }else{
      return redirect()->back()->withErrors(["El formato es incorrecto... Favor de subir formato PDF"]);
    }

    if (file_exists($ruta)) {
        unlink($ruta);
      }

    copy($file, $ruta);

    return redirect()->back()->with('update', 'El formato se subio correctamente');
    
  }
```

Comment: Te envía algún mensaje de error? Tiene los permisos para borrar?

Comment: No manda ningún error y si tiene permisos la ruta

Comment: ¿Si abres en "nuevo" PDF en disco es el último subido?